# Getting tenant name from azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I would like to retrieve the tenant name `THIS-THING-HERE.onmicrosoft.com` using Azure CLI. I can't really find in documentation.

EDIT:
When I'm calling azure account list I don't get user name in the domain provided since I'm login with corporate email:

```
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "46ee2f65-7112-4c96-ad0a-3ff6ca22a615",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Visual Studio Professional",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "1caf5d6b-58cb-40e6-88b3-eb9ab9c0c010",
    "user": {
      "name": "a.krajniak@avanade.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "1efd84d6-173f-42cc-80db-7b2c17eb0edd",
    "isDefault": false,
    "name": "Microsoft Azure Enterprise",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "c48d02ad-7efd-4910-9b51-ebb7a4b75379",
    "user": {
      "name": "a.krajniak@avanade.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: consider accepting this answer ;)

Comment: I wish microsoft made it as easy as `az account tenant list`

Answer (score 7):

I use this:

```
az account list --query "[?isDefault].tenantId | [0]" --output tsv
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as he wants the tenant name, not the tenantId.

Answer (score 5):

You could use this command:

```
az ad signed-in-user show --query 'userPrincipalName' | cut -d '@' -f 2 | sed 's/\"//'
```

this will take user upn and take the last part

Comment: I'm getting
`az ad: 'signed-in-user' is not in the 'az ad' command group. See 'az ad --help'`

Comment: update your azure cli, or use any other place where it shows your upn, like `az account show`

Comment: I've update my azure cli on my mac, still the same. Also I searched for this command in documentation without any luck

Comment: like i said, use another query: `az account show --query 'user.name' | cut -d '@' -f 2 | sed 's/\"//'`

Comment: This only works if the current user is in the directory and not of type guest

Comment: probably, I didnt test all the possible scenarios @hofnarwillie

Comment: 'cut' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: you using powershell or smth? use split-string with replace in that case

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved in a one-liner thanks to the `az rest` subcommand:

This works for tenant users but also guests users and CSP administrators.

```
az rest --method get --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains --query 'value[?isDefault].id' -o tsv
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the primary domain of an Azure tenant using bash, az cli, curl and jq:

```
$ az login
$ AZURE_TOKEN_ID=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph --query accessToken --output tsv)
$ curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${AZURE_TOKEN_ID}" --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains' | jq -r '.value[] | select(.isDefault == true) | {id}[]'
```

The result will be something like:

```
mydomain.onmicrosoft.com
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve tenant name:

In the Azure CLI (I use GNU/Linux):

```
$ azure login  # add "-e AzureChinaCloud" if you're using Azure China
```

This will ask you to login via https://aka.ms/devicelogin or https://aka.ms/deviceloginchina

```
    $ azure account show

 {
  "environmentName": "AzureCloud",
  "id": "aaabbbcccdd-eeff-gghh-iijj-abcdef256984",
  "isDefault": true,
  "name": "MSDN Subscription",
  "state": "Enabled",
  "tenantId": "ggzzttyyh-56rg-op4e-iixx-kiednd256",
  "user": {
    "cloudShellID": true,
    "name": "paul@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "type": "user"
          }
 }
```

To get tenant ID:

```
az account list | jq -r '.[].tenantId'
```

To get tenant name:

```
az account list | jq -r '.[].user'.name
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Use `az ad signed-in-user show --query 'userPrincipalName'`

Comment: Only works if the user is in the current directory and not a guest user

Comment: That is a subscription name, not a tenancy name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get the list of tenants, it has a displayName property:

```
az rest --method get --url '/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01'
```

If you have access to customer tenancies through Azure Lighthouse you can display these by appending `$includeAllTenantCategories=true`

Passing this to az cli and escaping the $ sign in powershell would result in the following command

```
az rest --method get --url '/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01' --url-parameters `$includeAllTenantCategories=true
```

Comment: FYI thie REST endpoint does not work with access tokens from service principals or managed identities, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/21920